# Postfix - RBL check behind relayhost

Tags: postfix, smtp, rbl

We are running a mail server which is responsible for a sub-domain (say, dom1.example.com). All the mails sent from Internet are received through our relayhost (mail server responsible for example.com).

I want to perform RBL/RHS checks in Postfix (v2.7.0) or any policy server before accepting the mail. All the client restrictions (reject_rbl_client, etc.) are of no use as our relayhost is a client for our mail server and RBL checks are not getting performed on source IP.

Is there any way to specify that RBL check should be done on source IP instead of our relayhost?

Answer (score 2):

Have the mail sent directly to your server, or do the RBL checks on the other server.

To send the mail directly to your server, just add appropriate MX records. For example:

```
dom1  IN  MX  0 mail.dom1.example.com.
```

Comment: Sadly, it is not possible :(

Comment: Then you must figure out how to make it possible.

Comment: I didn't mean to sound rude, but by not possible I meant it is "company policy". The only MX record visible to outside world is of example.com and all the mails are then forwarded to respective mail servers responsible for sub-domains.

Comment: Then you do the RBL checks on the other server, or change the company policy.