# How to get postfix to check all 'Recieved:' headers against an RBL?

Tags: postfix, spam, rbl, smtpd

I have several rbls listed in `smtpd_client_restrictions`, but this only checks the client IP against the RBLS. Is there any way to get postfix to check each `Recieved:` line against the RBL like spamassassin does?

Spamassassin tags blacklisted IPs in `Received:` as `RCVD_IN_BL_xxx`.

I'm assuming a content filter needs to be added. I could write one but would like to know if any such thing already exists.

[Postfix - RBL check behind relayhost](https://serverfault.com/questions/511273/postfix-rbl-check-behind-relayhost) is somewhat related.

Comment: Since every header in the delivery chain before the actual host contacting your server can be forged that may not be a good approach

Comment: @HBruijn Do you expect forgeries intended to decrease reputation?  :-)

Answer (score 1):

For low load mail site I would recommend deploying spamassassin **in network tests mode** via milter.
It would allow you to reject message during SMTP without taking over responsibility to generate bounce messages.

Postfix supports milters like sendmail does.

**Spamassassin capable milter list:**
https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/IntegratedInMta

**WARNINGS**:

1. Use higher than usuall spam threshold for rejecting/bouncing messages.
2. Some milters by default deploy spamassassin in "local tests only" mode to make scan faster.
3. spamassassin scan in network mode may take a few seconds - it may be too long for heavy load sites